# Converting byte stream to .wav file

Tags: java, sockets, audio, arrays, wav

I am trying to make a program which sends a file from a server to a client (via sockets). The server converts a .wav file to a byte array and sends that to the client. My problem though is that I can't play the .wav file (at the client) because it is corrupted. I have done some research and found out that for this you can't just use a FileOutputStream or BufferedOutputStream. I just don't know how to convert the byte array to the .wav file so it can be played. Maybe someone knows the answer for me?

Server code:

```
package me.Ciaran.simplefileserver;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleFileServer {

public final static int SOCKET_PORT = 13267;  // you may change this
public final static String FILE_TO_SEND = "D:/server/plugins/TBMCAudioServer/music/DLTALL.wav";  // you may change this

public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
FileInputStream fis = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
OutputStream os = null;
ServerSocket servsock = null;
Socket sock = null;
try {
  servsock = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT);
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    try {
      sock = servsock.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
      // send file

      final File myFile= new File(FILE_TO_SEND); //sdcard/DCIM.JPG
      byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];
      fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
      try {
          os = sock.getOutputStream();
          DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
          dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());     
          dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
          int read;
          while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
              dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
          }

      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("Done.");
    }
    finally {
      if (bis != null) bis.close();
      if (os != null) os.close();
      if (sock!=null) sock.close();
    }
  }
}
finally {
  if (servsock != null) servsock.close();
}
}
}
```

and the client code:

```
package me.Ciaran.simplefileclient;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleFileClient {

public final static int SOCKET_PORT = 13267;      // you may change this
public final static String SERVER = "127.0.0.1";  // localhost
public final static String
   FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "C:/Users/Ciaran/Documents/TESTEN/music/DLTALL.wav";  // you may change this, I give a
                                                        // different name because i don't want to
                                                        // overwrite the one used by server...

public final static int FILE_SIZE = 6022386; // file size temporary hard coded
                                           // should bigger than the file to be downloaded

@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
Socket sock = null;
try {
  sock = new Socket(SERVER, SOCKET_PORT);
  System.out.println("Connecting...");

  // receive file

  InputStream in;
  int bufferSize=0;

  try {
      bufferSize=sock.getReceiveBufferSize();
      in=sock.getInputStream();
      DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
      String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
      System.out.println(fileName);
      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      int read;
      while((read = clientData.read(buffer)) != -1){
          output.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }

  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED
      + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
}
finally {
  if (fos != null) fos.close();
  if (bos != null) bos.close();
  if (sock != null) sock.close();
}
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

EDIT: I have compared two music files online and I found out that Java added a ton of whitespaces at the beginning of the file. That is why it won't run. Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: A file is a file, and it doesn't really matter what kind of file it is if you're merely transmitting it unchanged.  Either you're converting the file into a byte stream and then faithfully reconstructing the file from the byte stream on the receiving end, or you are omitting data from the byte stream or adding information that wasn't there, and it's no longer the same file.  I suggest you do a comparison of the original file to the transmitted one, and find out what the differences are.

Comment: Are you trying to write a streaming player?

Comment: if i try this on one computer, so convert into byte array (with fileinputstream) and write to a copy file (with fileoutputstream) it works. But is this system independet actually?

Comment: On server side you do a `writeLong` with the array length but on client side there is no corresponding `readLong`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried a comparison with a program called: ExamDiff. It says that the files are not the same, but it doesn't say anything more. And I am writing a sort of streaming player. The only difference is that I send the file before and then let it play.

Comment: @T_01 What do you mean by independent?

Comment: @vanje I tried that as well but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: i mean, maybe a file has to be constructed another way (the first bytes for codec and so on) on another system...

Comment: but that doesnt make any sense, because if i download a file i can play it. sorry for this stupid thoughts ^^